# Symfony3.0 When saving a form with Entity Type dropdown; SQL error cannot insert null

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Using Symfony 3.0, I have a form with a dropdown list generated from a Doctrine Entity. When I complete the form & Submit I can see in the profiler that the dropdown value has been passed through correctly, yet I get the following error:
Any idea what might be happening?  *EDIT* I am not wanting to pass a null value. The form is passing in the selected value from the entity dropdown. But the insert into the db doesn't seem to be using this?

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot
insert the value NULL into column 'account_type', table 'CRM.dbo.accounts';
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

The form is: (AccountType.php)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('accountTypeId', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:AccountType',
            'choice_label' => 'typeName',
            //'label' => 'Account Type',
        ))
        ->add('name')
        ->add('notes', null, array('label' => 'Long Name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('address')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('region')
        ->add('country', CountryType::class)
        ->add('postcode')
        ->add('telephone', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('website', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('email', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}
```

Controller: (AccountController.php)

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $account = new Account();

    $form = $this->createForm(AccountType::class, $account);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        try {
            // create account
            //$account = $form->getData();

            // save data to db
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($account);
            $em->flush();

            // add flash message and return to profile
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Account: ' . $account->getName() .' created successfully.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('accounts');
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('accounts');
        }
    }

    // load form for new account
    return $this->render('accounts/add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

Account Model relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccountType", inversedBy="accounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_type", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $accountTypeName;
```

AccountType Model relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="accountTypeName")
 */
private $accounts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now I feel really dumb! 
After all this, I was using the wrong variable in my account form. 
I was using the account type id in my entity. Instead I should have been using the variable set in the relationship:

My form was using:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="account_type")
 */
private $accountTypeId;
```

Form:

```
$builder
        ->add('accountTypeId', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:AccountType',
            'choice_label' => 'typeName',
            //'label' => 'Account Type',
        ))
```

I have now changed the form to be:

```
$builder
        ->add('accountTypeName', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:AccountType',
            'choice_label' => 'typeName',
            //'label' => 'Account Type',
        ))
```

From :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccountType", inversedBy="accounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_type", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $accountTypeName;
```

Which obviously works!!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Account Entity according to this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccountType", inversedBy="accounts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $accountTypeName;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue. I can't work out why the form data is being passed in, yet the insert into the table looks like the account_type is null - when it shouldn't be

Comment: did you update the schema php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: try to add ->add('accountTypeId', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:AccountType','required' => false,                like that you cannot submit the form with empty value

Comment: The problem with changing the nullable value in the entity, is there are other tables that depend on it, so it doesn't allow you to set to allow nulls.

I mentioned in my post. its not the data being submitted in the form that is the issue. I can see that this data is successfully posted as the correct ID.